# GCP Notification channel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcloud, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have set up a notification channel for Console Cloud mobile Application:

[image]

Now I would like to be able to add the notification to alerting via Terraform, so I would like to get the notification channel id:

```
gcloud alpha monitoring channels list
```

This command returns all the channels, but this one not.

Also when trying to plan with Terraform, I can discover the id (projects/goout-cloud/notificationChannels/#####), however when I try to add it to any alert Terraform section, I will always get:

```
Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
```

Comment: Can you indicate if you followed the instructions listed in [Mobile App](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#mobile-app)?

Comment: Yes, the channel is correctly added and can be used when using the online GCP console. It just cannot be seen via the `gcloud alpha monitoring` command line tool, nor from Terraform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consulted this question internally,

Any sort of interaction - including get, create and update to Mobile App Channels through the API is **not** possible and gives 404. This notification channel cannot be used by non-Google internal API clients. As such, automation is not currently possible.

The Cloud Stackdriver Monitoring team is aware of this limitation, but it solving this issue is not on the priority list, hence there is no ETA for implementation any time soon.

---

There is a [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167959059) regarding this topic, if you want to receive updates, please star the issue.

Comment: Is there any internal issue on this? I would like to subscribe to updates.

Comment: You can have the updates by starring this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167959059