# Is it possible to use a notification channel from a different project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm currently setting up an AlertPolicy in GCP. I have been able to succesfully connect this AlertPolicy with a Notification Channel that I created in the same project.

So far so good, but what I really want to do is define all my Notification Channels in the same project. So I made a Notification Channel in a separate project, but when I go back to the AlertPolicy in the first project, I cannot see that Notification Channel, it doesn't seem to look outside of the current project.

The thing is, when I download the JSON for the AlertPolicy I see that the Notification Channel is referred to by a "fully qualified resource identifier":

```
projects/my-specific-project/notificationChannels/8038986124785870038
```

This makes me think that it should be possible to use a Notification Channel from a different project.

Could someone advise on whether this is possible?

Comment: I found the same case of your issue, you can check this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774006/gcp-notification-channel) to verify if your the same problem.

Comment: I don't think so, this problem seems specific to some kind of special internal notification channel for that use case.